# How to get caller file name in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, stack-trace

I have a Node class which I import in many of my projects modules Once imported into required module I create object of it and then call related methods of that object.

### My question is how do I get the object caller's file name in my class file without explicitly passing so

I don't want to use **module.parent.filename** as it only gives the file name of parent file and not of other files. After some R&D I came to know that there is a module called ***stack-trace*** which could provide me similar functionality. But when I  tried following code into my class I got the name of file itself in which the code was written and not the name of file  which was calling the object of that class

```
const stackTrace = require('stack-trace');
var trace = stackTrace.get()
console.log(trace[0].getFileName())
```

Answer (score 0):

[The manual](https://github.com/felixge/node-stack-trace#stacktracegetbelowfn) states, for `stackTrace.get()`:

> Returns an array of `CallSite` objects, *where element `0` is the current call site.*

You don't want the current call site, but the previous one, so you need to use `trace[1].getFileName()`

Comment: trace[1].getFileName() outputs only module.js

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand correctly: you have file `my-class.js` that exports a class, you have a file `a.js` that imports that class and instantiates it, and you want a method in the class to show `a.js`?

Comment: exactly thats what I wanted

Comment: That's what I'm testing, and it works just fine for me. Perhaps you should add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question demonstrating the problem.